# Странный вывод...

Tags: c++

```
printf("И : %s ",argv[j]);
```

В цикле вывожу параметры, которые ввел через консоль... но выводит всего по одному символу. К примеру : вместо ".cpp" - только ".", как исправить ?

Comment: ответ найден. Dex, спасибо :)

Comment: Звёздочку забыл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работает замечательно:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: нашел свою ошибку, спасибо :)

Comment: Тогда ответ стоило бы принять:)